# faceDetector.isOperational() is always returning false

Tags: android, google-vision, vision-api

I am using using google vision API to detect face from bitmap. But it is always returning false. It used to work previously but not now.

Here the code and verisons I am using.

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.4'
```

**Manifest**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="face" />
```

**Code**

```
 FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
            .build();

    if (faceDetector.isOperational()) {
        ...
        ...
```

But `faceDetector.isOperational()` **always returning false**. I checked in OPPO(5.1.1) and Moto(6.0)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes detector dependencies are downloaded when the app runs for the first time and not when the app installs. I have faced the same issue, the problem is either your network connection is not On or you don't have enough storage for download say 10% of the total space though it does not take that much space but downloads from Google Play Services does require good amount of storage.

It looks like the first time face detector is used on each device, some download is done by Google Play Services for once. Make sure your network connection is turn on and wait for a while after starting application.

Comment: are there any version limitation on this API?

Comment: No, But in some device it downloads some libraries when you code run for first time for face detector. I hope my answer is helpful to you.

Comment: I am facing the same problem of faceDetector.isOperational() returning false each time. I have tried all the suggested answers that appear when googled with the error message but not able to see it work on my Nokia 5 cellphone. My build.gradle version for play-services looks like below: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1'